# how to use Tomcat as Eclipse Server with Maven test scope

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

On a J2EE project working with Eclipse 4.4.1 we use a local Tomcat to test our application.
It's configured in the Eclipse **Servers** view.
The productive Platform already integrates a database driver. For the local test environment we use this one.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But it doesn't work until one changes the scope to compile. With compile Scope the local Tomcat configured in Eclipse starts correctly, without it complains about missing jdbc driver.
Is it possible to configure the Tomcat server to run in test scope? Starting in debug mode doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using maven dependency scope for wrong purpose. From [Maven POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html):

> test - this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for
>   normal use of the application, and is only available for the test
>   compilation and execution phases.

What you need are profiles. From [Maven POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html):

> A new feature of the POM 4.0 is the ability of a project to change
>   settings depending on the environment where it is being built. A
>   profile element contains both an optional activation (a profile
>   trigger) and the set of changes to be made to the POM if that profile
>   has been activated. For example, a project built for a test
>   environment may point to a different database than that of the final
>   deployment. Or dependencies may be pulled from different repositories
>   based upon the JDK version used.

So, try to add a profile to your test environment, like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

To activate this profile on eclipse, do this: Right Click on your project --> Maven --> Select Maven Profile... (on windows, just CTRL + ALT + P). Then, select the profile:

[image]

At the command line, you can do something like this to activate `test` profile:

```
mvn <lifecycles> -Ptest
```